useShinyJS can't be found
when i run the the shiny app on ESS, there is no problem with useShinyJs(). However, when I run the shiny app on RStudio, it says useShinyJS() can't be found with the following error message:
Warning: Error in useShinyjs: could not find function "useShinyjs"
  66: dots_list
  65: div
  62: fluidPage
   1: runApp

In my app.r:
packagesloaded <-
  c("tidyverse",
   "deSolve",
   "shinyjs",
   "shiny",
   "shinyhelper",
    "shinyvalidate",
    "shinyWidgets") |>
 lapply(FUN = require, character.only = TRUE) |>
  as.logical() |>
  all()
if (!packagesloaded) exit()

In my ui.r:
fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
     
     div(
          titlePanel("Compartmental Models of Epidemiology")
     ),
     navbarPage( details ommitted here...

I think it's the problem with order of execution of RStudio since the app can only run when I ctrl+Enter execute each line of code sequentially in the app.r file. Otherwise, if I simply run the app by pressing run app button, the function useShinyjs still is not found

Try adding an explict call to shinyjs::useShinyjs() and see if that works.

Please provide the list of packages you are calling in either the global.R or the server.R files.

It helps to include a reproducible example of the problem. That is the best way to get help on Stack Overflow.
